# javascript regular expression ignore condition between the text

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I have a text for example as below:

`"head1>data1,data2,data3|head2>data1,data2,data3|head3>data3,data4,data5**`

now I want to replace `">data1..|"` with `"|"`

I am using this: `".replace(/>\S+\||>\S+$/g,"|");"`

But this is not helping as it gives me data as below:

`"head1|head3|"` instead of `"head1|head2|head3|"`

I am unable to find the right method.

Comment: Use `>\S+?(?:\||$)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
>\S+?(?:\||$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ1xG6/1)

The point is to make `\S+` lazy, and to shorten the pattern we can use place the `>\S+?` before the alternation group.

**Pattern details**:

- `>\S+?` - a literal `>` followed with 1+ non-whitespace symbols but as few as possible up to
- `(?:\||$)` - a literal `|` or the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach :), was trying like this

```js
var str = "head1>data1,data2,data3|head2>data1,data2,data3|head3>data3,data4,data5";

console.log(str.replace(/>[a-z1-9,]+/g,"|").replace(/\|+/g, "|"));
```

`>[a-z1-9,]+` will select `>data1,data2,data3`

and then replaced multiple `|` with single `|`

:)

Comment: this was quite simple solution .. Thank you.

Comment: I believe in simplicity. :) happy to help.

Comment: Mark the correct/useful answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> >[a-z0-9,]+\|

and then replace this with single `|` every time.

Comment: Just wondering why you posted the exact same answer 1 hour  later?